# Ruby Yard Doc: preformatted code

Tags: ruby, yard

I've been trying to get yard doc to output preformatted code. I've tried @example but that isn't parsed. ++code++:: will create a code section but formatting is not preserved.

I'm using the default settings so I presume RDoc. Yard version: yard 0.8.7.6, Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

This is the section of comment:

```
# == Example
#       emitter = AsyncEmitter.new
#       emitter.on :error, lambda { |e| puts "Error: #{e}" }
#       emitter.on :data, lambda { |data| puts "Data: #{data}" }
#
#       begin
#               data = get_data_from_somewhere
#               emitter.emit :data, data
#       rescue Exception => e
#               emitter.emit :error, e
#       end
```

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces?

Comment: For the indentation? Tabs.

Comment: 'Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that is no longer maintained (2014-02-23)' as I am installing this Ruby to look at this question.

Comment: Thanks. It's still the debian default pkg.

Comment: Hoping you can accept an answer.  Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

If this is the goal:

[image: Screen Shot]

This is is how the file looks to create this:

```
# Example
#     emitter = AsyncEmitter.new
#     emitter.on :error, lambda { |e| puts "Error: #{e}" }
#     emitter.on :data, lambda { |data| puts "Data: #{data}" }
class AsyncEmitter

# Description and example
#     begin
#       data = get_data_from_somewhere
#       emitter.emit :data, data
#     rescue Exception => e
#       emitter.emit :error, e
#     end
  def get_data_from_somewhere
    # Your Code Here
  end
end
```

I used Bundler to get the environment set up, and this is the contents of the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'yard', '0.8.7.6'
gem 'redcarpet'
```

I used 4 spaces for indentation, not tabs. And I ensured that the blank line also includes the 4 spaces.

Comment: For that one little irritating part, simply add a newline after the "Description and example" and that will serve as the "Summary"

Comment: There it is. Spaces not tabs.Thanks.